# simple javascript regexp with urls

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with regExp.

I just want to parse incoming urls to my application.

Here is my current RegExp :

```
var regexp = new RegExp('/users','i');
"/users".test(regexp); //Should return true
"/users/".test(regexp); //should return true
"/users?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz".test(regexp); //Should return true
"/users/?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz".test(regexp); //should return true;
"/users?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz/10".test(regexp); //Should return false
"/users/?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz/10".test(regexp); //should return false;
"/users/10".test(regexp); //should return false
"/users/10/contracts".test(regexp); //Should return false
"/users/10/contracts/10".test(regexp); //Should return false
"/users/anythingElseThatIsNotAQuestionMark".test(regexp); //Should return false
```

Is anyone has the kindness to help me ?

Wish you a nice evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^\/users\/?(\?([^\/&=]+=[^\/&=]*&)*[^\/&=]+=[^\/&=]*)?$/i` should work and also confirm that the query is valid:

```js
var regexp = /^\/users\/?(\?([^\/&=]+=[^\/&=]*&)*[^\/&=]+=[^\/&=]*)?$/i;

function test(str) {
  document.write(str + ": ");
  document.write(regexp.test(str));
  document.write("<br/>");
}

test("/users"); //should return true
test("/users/"); //should return true
test("/users?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz"); //should return true
test("/users/?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz"); //should return true
test("/users?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz/10"); //should return false
test("/users/?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy&variableN=zzzz/10"); //should return false
test("/users/10"); //should return false
test("/users/10/contracts"); //should return false
test("/users/10/contracts/10"); //should return false
test("/users/anythingElseThatIsNotAQuestionMark"); //should return false
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way around `regexp.test("/users")`

> The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular
>   expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

Syntax

```
regexObj.test(str)
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all its `RegExp.test(String)`

Then this regex should do:

```
/^\/users\/?(?:\?[^\/]+)?$/i
```

Check it out: https://regex101.com/r/mK8dU4/1

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.